# Creating a list of files in a directory based on specific characters and create text file with these names

Tags: linux

I have files in a directory (filename1_R1, filename1_R2, filename2_R1, filename2_R2).

The following code reprints the full directory of each of these filenames on 4 lines

```
bash
echo -e "sample-id\tforward-absolute-filepath\treverse-absolute-filepath" > manifest.tsv 
for f in `ls *.gz`; do n=`basename $f`; echo -e "${n%_R*_001.fastq.gz}\t$PWD/$f\t$PWD/$f "; done >> manifest.tsv


txt
filename1   filepath/filename_R1    filepath/filename_R1
filename1   filepath/filename_R2    filepath/filename_R2
filename2   filepath/filename_R1    filepath/filename_R1
filename2   filepath/filename_R2    filepath/filename_R2
```

I would like it to print:

```
filename1   filepath/filename1_R1   filepath/filename1_R2
filename2   filepath/filename2_R1   filepath/filename2_R2
```

How do I get the code to only provide the path the R1 or R2 element of the files?

I am not sure how to properly get it to select file paths with specific characters.

Comment: You can pipe it into `uniq` for an easy way to get rid of duplicates.
`uniq` requires the inputs to be sorted, but if the bug always gives you the same file right next to each other, it should still work.